# How should my DTO class look like if I have to convert the following JSON into Java Object?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{ 
   "A":{ 
      "B":"a"
   },
   "C":[ 
      "b",
      "c"
   ],
   "D":"d"
}
```

Above is just a sample input. There can be similar nested structure too. I could think of using map as member variable in my DTO class. Will it be possible to come up with a DTO class if we don't know the exact structure and length of our JSON?

Comment: @azurefrog As you mentioned, a simple value, array or another object (which may recursively involve above 3) would be there in my JSON.

Comment: There is a site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which creates pojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need the following 3 classes to map from/to that JSON.

```java
class Root {
    @SerializedName("A")
    ClassA fieldA;

    @SerializedName("C")
    List<String> fieldC;

    @SerializedName("D")
    String fieldD;
}
```

```java
class ClassA {
    @SerializedName("B")
    String fieldB;
}
```

*Test*

```
Root root = new Root();
root.fieldA = new ClassA();
root.fieldA.fieldB = "a";
root.fieldC = Arrays.asList("b", "c");
root.fieldD = "d";
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(root));
```

*Output*

```json
{
  "A": {
    "B": "a"
  },
  "C": [
    "b",
    "c"
  ],
  "D": "d"
}
```